# UE4: Subclass problem: cannot access private member declared in parent class?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I get the following error:

```
  [...]\ClassB.cpp:7: erreur : C2248: 'UClassA::UClassA' : cannot access private member declared in class 'UClassA'
  [...]\ClassA.h:12: see declaration of 'AClassA::AClassA'
  [...]\ClassA.h:9: see declaration of 'AClassA'
```

when I create a subsubclass.

The problem occurs with the following code:

ClassA.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "ClassA.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class PROBUILDER_API AClassA : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    AClassA( const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer );

};
```

ClassA.cpp

```
#include "ProBuilder.h"
#include "ClassA.h"

AClassA::AClassA(const FObjectInitializer &ObjectInitializer):Super(ObjectInitializer)
{

}
```

ClassB.h

```
#pragma once

#include "ClassA.h"
#include "ClassB.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class PROBUILDER_API AClassB : public AClassA
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    AClassB( const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer );

};
```

ClassB.cpp

```
#include "ProBuilder.h"
#include "ClassB.h"


AClassB::AClassB(const FObjectInitializer &ObjectInitializer):Super(ObjectInitializer)
{

}
```

(I tried with a subclass of AActor and UMeshComponent and got the same errors)

Comment: Well yeah, you can't access private members from any other class (except friends). That's what private means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to set my constructor to public.